# Babel: "The keyword 'await' is reserved (53:24)"

Tags: node.js, meteor, async-await, babeljs

We're using async/await for our Meteor project. This syntax is everywhere in our resolvers.js. Everything has been working fine until we've upgraded to Node 6.7. Now it shows this error every time we try to build it:

"The keyword 'await' is reserved (53:24)"

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here is the content of my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-require", "babel-root-slash-import"]
}
```

Comment: Note that the exponential operator is moving from `stage-3` (implicitly included by `stage-2`) to the preset [`es2016`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2016/), and async/await and trailing function commas are moving to [`es2017`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2016/), so you should probably use those instead.

Comment: I tried to change "es2015" to "es2017", but still the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't change `es2015` to `es2017`, you should add `es2016` and `es2017` instead of `stage-2`. (`["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "react"]`). Anyways, it's not intended as a probable solution, just a "heads up" that it's going to change soon.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Okay, trying this one instead.

Comment: It still didn't work. Are there any other possible factors for this aside from the .babelrc?

Comment: I've also started having this problem and I'm on Node v6.3.1. I think it might be related to new versions of recently-released babel plugins

Comment: Yep, this has bitten us as well, on 6.6.0 and 6.7.0. Amazingly, pulling a shrinkwrap file from a known-working VM **did not** fix the issue.

Answer (score 25):

Just in case anyone else searches for this same issue, in my case it was user error, me.  I forgot to put the async keyword before the function name.[image]

Comment: If you have multiple arrow functions make sure you place `await` before the correct one. Example: `const result = (data, url) => async dispatch => { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out a solution to my own problem. I just excluded the .babelrc when doing a Meteor build since Meteor already has a package that supports ES6 syntax. I didn't totally remove the .babelrc because I will be needing it on tests and when running the Storybook which does not trigger a Meteor build.

Answer (score 1):

Await alone is invalid syntax. await needs to be called inside an async function like:

```
var aFunction = async function() {
  let aResponse = await get('aValue');
}
```